# How to merge multiple Arrays containing the same value in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, algorithm

I'm struggling to find the best way to merge *arrays* (or create new ones) by looking at their shared value.

```
List<String[]> dictionary = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

this is my "dictionary" filled with arrays of 2 words, for example it contains arrays:

```
["A","B"]
["B","C"]
["D","E"]
["F","C"]
["G","H"]
["T","D"]
```

I need to merge them by values they share, so for example the finished "dictionary" (or completely new list) would look like this:

```
["A","B","C","F"];
["D","E","T"];
["G","H"];
```

Also, the old arrays don't have to be removed they can stay in "dictionary" but I need the merged ones and I have hard time figuring it out.

Arrays don't have to be sorted at anyhow.

This is what i have so far and it is not working

```
    public static void SynonymsMerge(List<String[]> dictionary){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> newDictionary = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    for(int i=0;i < dictionary.size(); i++){
        ArrayList<String> synonyms = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int j=0; j < dictionary.get(i).length; j++){
            synonyms.add(dictionary.get(i)[j]);
        }
        newDictionary.add(synonyms);
    }
    for(int i=0;i< newDictionary.size();i++){
        for(int j=0; j < newDictionary.size();j++){
            for (int k=0; k < newDictionary.get(j).size() ;k++) {
                    if (newDictionary.get(i).equals(newDictionary.get(j)))
                        continue;
                    if (newDictionary.get(i).contains(newDictionary.get(j).get(k)))
                        newDictionary.get(i).addAll(newDictionary.get(j));
```

Comment: you will always have to create new arrays, as Java doesn't support to resize existing arrays.

Comment: ...and therefore: is it possible to work just with lists, at least as an intermediate step? It would be so much easier to merge them.

Comment: as we know in java static array can not be modified , so instead of using List<String[]> use can use *List<ArrayList<String>> dictionary = new ArrayList<>()*  it will give more flexibility

Comment: Do you want an optimized solution or just brute forcing?

Comment: @Bahij.Mik "I'm struggling to find the **best way** to merge arrays"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, here is the code. I changed the input type from `List<String[]>` to `List<List<String>>` as it does not really make sense to mix up both Lists and Arrays. This also applies to the output type.

## The code

```java
public static List<List<String>> merge(List<List<String>> dictionary) {
        List<List<String>> newDictionary = new ArrayList<>();

        for (List<String> stringPair : dictionary) {

            List<Integer> matchIndices = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < newDictionary.size(); i++) {
                List<String> newStrings = newDictionary.get(i);

                for (String str : stringPair) {
                    if (newStrings.contains(str)) {
                        matchIndices.add(i);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (matchIndices.size() == 0) {
                newDictionary.addAll(new ArrayList<List<String>>(Collections.singleton(new ArrayList<>(stringPair))));
                continue;
            }

            matchIndices.sort(Integer::compareTo);

            if (matchIndices.size() == 1) {
                newDictionary.get(matchIndices.get(0)).addAll(new ArrayList<>(stringPair));
            } else {
                int last = matchIndices.remove(0);
                while (matchIndices.size() > 0) {
                    int i = matchIndices.get(0);
                    newDictionary.get(last).addAll(newDictionary.get(i));
                    newDictionary.remove(i);
                    matchIndices.remove(0);
                    matchIndices = new ArrayList<>(matchIndices.stream().map(a -> a - 1).toList());
                }
            }
        }
        newDictionary = newDictionary.stream()
                .map(strings -> strings.stream().distinct().toList())
                .toList();

        return newDictionary;
    }
```

## How does it work?

- `dictionary` the input of type `List<List<String>>` (inner List has max size of 2, even though the function would work with even more strings in theory)
- `newDictionary` the output of the function of type `List<List<String>>`

The following code is executed for every input pair/List of strings in `directory`

1. Get all the existing different "groups" (their indicies) in `newDictionary` in which the strings from the par are already present. This List of indices is called `matchIndices`
   Example: `stringPair`=["A","E"]  `newDictionary`:[["I", "A", "O"], ["P", "D"]] would result in `matchIndices`=[0] because only "A" is present one time in the first element of `newDictionary`
2. If `matchIndices.size()` is 0, create a new group in `newDictionary` with the string pair. Back to 1.
3. If `matchIndices.size()` is 1, append the strings from the pair to the specific `newDictionary` group with the index specified in `matchIndices`. Back to 1.
4. If `matchIndices.size()` is greater than 1, that means that multiple groups from `newDictionary` with the indices specified in `matchIndices` will have to be merged together in the `for`-loop. Back to 1.

In the end we have to make sure there are no duplicates in the Lists in  `newDictionary`.

## Main method

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<String>> dictionary = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                List.of("A", "B"),
                List.of("B", "C"),
                List.of("D", "E"),
                List.of("F", "C"),
                List.of("G", "H"),
                List.of("T", "D")));
        
        System.out.println(merge(dictionary));
    }
```

## Why do we need step 4?

In your specific example we don't have to merge multiple groups.
But with input data like this

```java
List<List<String>> dictionary = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
                List.of("A", "B"),
                List.of("B", "C"),
                List.of("D", "E"),
                List.of("F", "E"),
                List.of("E", "A")));
```

we eventually come to the point where `newDictionary=[[A, B, B, C], [D, E, F, E]]` and we have to try to insert `[E, A]`. Here both groups from `newDictionary` will have to be merged together.
This then results in the output of `[[A, B, C, D, E, F]]`, where both groups are merged and removed duplicates.

### P.s.

I am not really happy with this solution as it is not really clear what is actually going on, but I'm still posting this, because you said you would be happy with any solution. :)

Comment: Multiple occurrences of strings are only filtered out in the end, which results in this intermediate representation.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Stackoverflow and don't see why I would post the output, which OP already specified again. Also the output `[[A, B, C, D, E, F]]` is for the specific input case `[[A, B], [B, C], [D, E], [F, E], [E, A]]`, which was not asked for, but I felt like I would have to include it to properly explain why step 4 was needed.

Just to make sure. Is it common practise to post the output wanted by OP again?

Comment: HI so i tried your solution and on first attempt it works fine but when i use it again it misses some words and i have no idea why. Is there any way we could chat ?

Comment: Your code requires an improvement both in terms of stile and performance. **1.** It's not a very bright idea to cram all the logic into a single method. It'll be nicer to split it into several narrow-focused methods. **2.** I have to think more carefully when you are choosing data structures (and their implementations, i.e. collections). Don't use `ArrayList` everywhere. The way you are using `matchIndices` clearly indicates that it has to be a stack and not a list (class `Stack` is legacy` don't use it, you need implementation of the `Deque` interface).

Comment: With this values the word "wood" doesnt get included in the merged dictionary https://imgur.com/boVpOfb    @FlorianHartung

Comment: *Is it common practise to post the output wanted by OP again?* - It makes sense to use the input listed in the question because everyone ho read the question have seen it and had an opportunity to challenge the correctness of expected output. But it is not mandatory and, sure, you can use any input, especially if OP's example is not sufficient to caver all cases required. You've listed two `dictionaries` and a single output, it looks confusing.

Comment: Thank you for the solutions it really helped i just need to edit it so the duplications wont get removed because it deletes some values completely

Comment: @kpcttobee What what your input when the word "wood" didn't get included? In the image you attached I can only see the values of `newDictionary`.
@AlexanderIvanchenko Also thanks for your suggestion to use a `Deque`, to be honest I've never used them but I'm gonna make sure to look into it!

Comment: @FlorianHartung https://imgur.com/a/hn6emV9 Ok so the words that are not inside the [] are the words we are trying to merge, basically the A B C D and so on that i mentioned in the question and words in [ ] are results of merging, as you can see it works almost perfectly but "wood" gets removed.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem you need to connect `A` with `B` (*and vice versa*), then `C` with `B` and `C` with `F` and so on. A lot of intersections and a lot of cycles.

And that is the perfect case to utilize a [*Graph*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) as data structure.

To be precise, this dataset could be represented as a ***cyclic undirected disjointed graph***, that contains several [*connected components*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)). And in terms of *graph theory*, this task boils down to discovering all ***components*** in the *graph*.

For that, we need to take the following steps:

- Create and initialize the *graph* by parsing the input data.
- Iterate over the collection of *vertices* of the *graph*, and traverse every encountered connected *component*. Each *vertex* that wasn't seen previously indicates that a *component* to which it belongs also hasn't been yet discovered.
  As traversal algorithm I've chosen [Depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (but for the purpose of this task *Breadth first search* algorithm will also work fine).

*Implementation:*

```
public class Graph {
    private Map<String, Vertex> vertexByName = new HashMap<>();
    
    private Graph() {} // no way and no need to invoke this constractor outside the class
    
    public static Graph getInstance(List<List<String>> dictionary) { // method responsible for instantiation and initialization of the graph
        Graph graph = new Graph();
        graph.init(dictionary);
        return graph;
    }
    
    private void init(List<List<String>> dictionary) {
        for (List<String> list: dictionary) {
            for (String name: list) {
                addVertex(name, list);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void addVertex(String name, List<String> neighbours) {
        
        Vertex cur = vertexByName.computeIfAbsent(name, Vertex::new);
    
        for (String neighbourName: neighbours) {
            if (neighbourName.equals(name)) continue;
        
            Vertex neighbour = vertexByName.computeIfAbsent(neighbourName, Vertex::new);
            cur.addNeighbour(neighbour);
            neighbour.addNeighbour(cur); // this graph is undirectional, i.e. both vertices in each connected pair should hold a reference to one another
        }
    }
    
    public List<List<String>> getComponents() {
        List<List<String>> components = new ArrayList<>();
        
        Set<Vertex> seen = new HashSet<>();
        for (Vertex vertex: vertexByName.values()) {
            if (seen.contains(vertex)) continue;
            
            components.add(getComponentNames(vertex, seen));
        }
        return components;
    }

    // Depth first search implementation
    private List<String> getComponentNames(Vertex vertex, Set<Vertex> seen) {
        Deque<Vertex> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        stack.push(vertex);
        seen.add(vertex);
        
        while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex current = stack.pop();
            names.add(current.getName());
            
            for (Vertex neighbour: current.getNeighbours()) {
                if (seen.contains(neighbour)) continue;
                
                seen.add(neighbour);
                stack.push(neighbour);
            }
        }
        return names;
    }
    
    private class Vertex {
        private String name;
        private Set<Vertex> neighbours = new HashSet<>();
        
        public Vertex(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        public Vertex(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        
        public boolean addNeighbour(Vertex neighbour) {
            return neighbours.add(neighbour);
        }
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    
        public Set<Vertex> getNeighbours() {
            return neighbours;
        }
    }
}
```

`main()` - demo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<String>> dictionary =
        List.of(List.of("A","B"), List.of("B","C"),
                List.of("D","E"), List.of("F","C"),
                List.of("G","H"), List.of("T","D"));
    
    Graph graph = Graph.getInstance(dictionary);
    List<List<String>> componentNames = graph.getComponents();

    System.out.println(componentNames);
}
```

**Output**

```
[[A, B, C, F], [T, D, E], [G, H]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Un-refined first thought - **Index the arrays, and then merge them. Repeat.**

1. Iterate over your arrays in the ArrayList;
2. Index the items in the array;
3. Merge the items that are overlapping;
4. Repeat the same process over the merged result, until there is no overlap.

---

Using your example:

```
[A, B] (Call this #1 array)
[B, C] (Call this #2 array)
[D, E] (Call this #3 array)
[F, C] (Call this #4 array)
[G, H] (Call this #5 array)
[T, D] (Call this #6 array)
```

Now, prepare the index like:

```
A -> 1   (because A occurs only in array 1)
B -> 1,2 (because B occurs in array 1 and 2)
C -> 2,4 ...
D -> 3,6 ...
E -> 3   ...
F -> 4   ...
G -> 5   ...
T -> 6   ...
```

Looking at the above index, we know that we should merge 1 and 2, 2 and 4, and, 3 and 6. This will give us:

```
[A, B, C] (This is our new #1)
[B, C, F] (This is our new #2)
[D, E, T] (This is our new #3)
[G, H]    (This is our new #4)
```

Repeat the steps with your new ArrayList of arrays. Re-indexing gives...

```
A -> 1
B -> 1,2
C -> 1,2
D -> 3
E -> 3
F -> 2
G -> 4
H -> 4
T -> 3
```

Merge the overlaps again. This time only 1 and 2 overlap. Merging it will give you:

```
[A, B, C, F] (This is our new #1)
[D, E, T]    (This is our new #2)
[G, H]       (This is our new #3)
```

Once again, re-index,

```
A -> 1
B -> 1
C -> 1
D -> 2
E -> 3
F -> 1
G -> 3
H -> 3
T -> 2
```

Since there are no overlapping arrays this time, there is nothing more to merge and that's the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a solution using Union find, so the goal here is to iterate over all the Strings and while doing so finding the common "leader".

After doing that we will iterate over the dictionary again but this time each String will have a leader, we will bind them to a common leader and then create the merged dictionary

```
public class UnionFind
{
    private Map<String, String> graph;

    public UnionFind()
    {
        graph = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public String find(String str)
    {
        if (str == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid String");

        if (graph.getOrDefault(str, str).equals(str))
            graph.put(str, str);
        else 
            graph.put(str, find(graph.get(str)));

        return graph.get(str);
    }

    public void union(String str1, String str2)
    {
        String root1 = find(str1);
        String root2 = find(str2);


        if (!root1.equals(root2))
        {
            if (root1.equals(str1)) graph.put(graph.get(root1), graph.get(root2));
            else graph.put(graph.get(root2), graph.get(root1));
        }
    }
```

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<List<String>> dictionary = prepareDictionary();

        UnionFind unionFind = new UnionFind();

        for (List<String> list : dictionary)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++)
            {
                unionFind.union(list.get(i - 1), list.get(i));
            }
        }

        Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (List<String> list : dictionary)
        {
            for (String str : list)
            {
                String parent = unionFind.find(str);
                if (!map.containsKey(parent))
                    map.put(parent, new LinkedHashSet<>());

                map.get(parent).add(str);
            }
        }

        List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            result.add(new ArrayList<>(entry.getValue()));
        }

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static List<List<String>> prepareDictionary()
    {
        List<List<String>> dictionary = new ArrayList<>();

        dictionary.add(Arrays.asList("A", "B"));
        dictionary.add(Arrays.asList("B", "C"));
        dictionary.add(Arrays.asList("D", "E"));
        dictionary.add(Arrays.asList("F", "C"));
        dictionary.add(Arrays.asList("G", "H"));
        dictionary.add(Arrays.asList("T", "D"));

        return dictionary;
    }
```

result:

```
[[A, B, C, F], [D, E, T], [G, H]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another solution with set of strings for your structure

```
public void merge(List<String[]> dictionary) {
    List<Set<String>> dictionaryList = dictionary.stream()
            .map(x -> new HashSet<> (Arrays.asList(x))).collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (int i = 0; i < dictionaryList.size() ; i++){
        Set list = dictionaryList.get(i);

        for (int j = i + 1; j < dictionaryList.size() ; j++){
            Set otherList = dictionaryList.get(j);
            Set result = (Set) list.stream().filter(otherList::contains).collect(Collectors.toSet());

            if (!result.isEmpty()) {
                list.addAll(otherList);
                dictionaryList.remove(j);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(dictionaryList);
}
```

Result

```
[[A, B, C, F], [D, T, E], [G, H]]
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers were great thank you! However i couldn't use them because maybe i will need to explain the code and i was not understanding them fully (firts time coding in java yaaay!). What i did in the end was:
i saved all the input into list of hashsets because hashsets cant duplicate values, then i ran all the input through the 2 for(nested) loops with if statment

```
if(return !Collections.disjoint(hashset1,hashset2);)
```

after that i merged them using `set.addAll(hashset1); set.addAll(hashset2);`

however it was still not complete and there were a few sets that should have been merged but weren't. so i ran it through the 2for(nested) loops again with same if statement and it worked(i hope). It worked on input with 2000words and i hope it works on input with more words :D
Thank everybody for being so helpful.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please respect your readers enough to use proper case and punctuation. This site is meant to be more like Wikipedia, and less like a casual chat room.